# Implementing a window info / status bar in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, swiftui

Is it possible to implement a Finder-like bottom bar / status bar in SwiftUI? I don't mean a menubar extra, I mean a bar at the bottom of the window that shows info with a gradient background like this:

[image: Finder bottom bar]

Here's another example in Transmit:

[image: Transmit bottom bar]

- I tried the `bottomBar` toolbar API, but it is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900295/toolbar-at-bottom-on-macos-with-swiftui) on macOS
- There was a similar question that was [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76478319/statusbar-on-macos-using-swiftui) due to not following the rules
- This code gets me "somewhat close" (from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/position-view-at-the-bottom-of-another-view-shouldn-t-this-be-easy/10937)). I could flesh it out with a custom background, extract it to a component etc. but it still feels like a hack, I'm looking for a better way to do it.

```swift
VStack {
    HStack {
        ProgressView()
        Text("Doing something...")
    }
}.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottomLeading)
```

[image: vstack frame hack]

Comment: Hey Josh, welcome to the site! I have no idea why is this is closed as needing more focus. I think this is a perfectly clear, well asked question, with fantastic references to existing materials and why they didn't work for you. As far as I'm concerned, this is a very well asked question, especially for a first-timer, bravo!